# Check if any link from list contain any word from list

Tags: python

I need to check whether any word from words_list is element of phrases in <class 'generator'> containing site internal links - internal_links

```
>>>words_list = ['contact', 'Contact', 'Kontakt', 'kontakt', 'about', 'About us', ...]
>>>print(type(internal_links))
<class 'generator'>
>>>internal_links = list(internal_links)
>>>print(internal_links)
['link_1', 'link_2', '/any_sentence/contact', '/any_sentence/any_sentence/about_our_company', 'link_5 ',(...), 'link_n']
```

And i need to return list of this 2 links:

```
returned_list = ['/any_sentence/contact', '/any_sentence/any_sentence/about_our_company']
```

First link contains word 'contact', and second contains word 'about'.

I wouldn't be satisfied loop in loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
[i for j in words_list for i in internal_links if j in i]
```

?

Comment: maybe with more descriptive iterables? Like `i` -> `link`, `j` -> `word`